# Building multiple backends for Raku fails

Tags: perl, raku, rakudo

After reading `README.md` at https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo specifically [here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo#multiple-backends-at-the-same-time), I ventured on building multiple backends for rakudo.

I used 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 to do that. First I installed

- `build essential`, `libencode-perl`
- `default-jdk` to prepare the machine for compiling rakudo.

After cloning the repo, when I run the command `perl Configure.pl --backends=moar,jvm --prefix=/usr`, I get the following error:

```
root@1145eac1ed77:/rakudo# perl Configure.pl --backends=moar,jvm --prefix=/usr
No pre-existing installed file found at /usr/bin/nqp-m
No pre-existing installed file found at /usr/bin/nqp-j
No pre-existing installed file found at /usr/bin/nqp-m
No pre-existing installed file found at /usr/bin/nqp-j
Use of uninitialized value $str in substitution (s///) at /rakudo/3rdparty/nqp-configure/lib/NQP/Config.pm line 1420.
Use of uninitialized value $str in substitution (s///) at /rakudo/3rdparty/nqp-configure/lib/NQP/Config.pm line 1421.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 361.
Use of uninitialized value in quotemeta at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 371.
Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 371.
Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 371.
Use of uninitialized value in quotemeta at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 373.
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 414.
Redundant argument in sprintf at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 414.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 423.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 423.
Using /usr/bin/nqp-m (version  / MoarVM ).
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 428.
Redundant argument in sprintf at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 428.
===SORRY!===
  jvm::runtime.jars value not available from /usr/bin/nqp-j --show-config.

  To automatically clone (git) and build a copy of NQP 2020.02.1-154-ga7b0b7be2,
  try re-running Configure.pl with the '--gen-moar' option.
  Or, use '--prefix=' to explicitly specify the path where the NQP and MoarVM
  executables can be found that are use to build Rakudo. at /rakudo/3rdparty/nqp-configure/lib/NQP/Config.pm line 192.
 at /rakudo/3rdparty/nqp-configure/lib/NQP/Config.pm line 34.
        NQP::Config::__ANON__("===SORRY!===\x{a}  jvm::runtime.jars value not available from /us"...) called at /rakudo/3rdparty/nqp-configure/lib/NQP/Config.pm line 192
        NQP::Config::sorry(NQP::Config::Rakudo=HASH(0x55e4cb9c5258), "jvm::runtime.jars value not available from /usr/bin/nqp-j --s"..., "\x{a}To automatically clone (git) and build a copy of NQP 2020.02"..., "try re-running Configure.pl with the '--gen-moar' option.", "Or, use '--prefix=' to explicitly specify the path where the "..., "executables can be found that are use to build Rakudo.") called at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 576
        NQP::Config::Rakudo::post_active_backends(NQP::Config::Rakudo=HASH(0x55e4cb9c5258)) called at /rakudo/3rdparty/nqp-configure/lib/NQP/Config.pm line 660
        NQP::Config::configure_active_backends(NQP::Config::Rakudo=HASH(0x55e4cb9c5258)) called at /rakudo/tools/lib/NQP/Config/Rakudo.pm line 473
        NQP::Config::Rakudo::configure_active_backends(NQP::Config::Rakudo=HASH(0x55e4cb9c5258)) called at Configure.pl line 102
```

How can it be fixed?

I was wondering what `ALL` in the command `perl Configure.pl --backends=ALL` refers to.

There was a project (still there merged in master I guess) **Rakudo.js** [here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/pawel_murias/2019/10/wip-rakudojs-final-grant-update-1.html) and [here](https://perl6.github.io/6pad). Is this the Javascript backend?
Does that `ALL` means `moar`, `jvm` and `Javascript` backends?

Comment: You didn’t do —gen-nqp or —gen-moar like the error message explicitly says you need to do if e.g. moarvm is not already installed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by @ugexe, I was missing `--gen-moar` in my command.

For future reference, I want to document what I learned after repeated attempts of trying to build `Rakudo`.

#### Moar and JVM backends

---

For building `moar` and `jvm` backends you need the dependencies

```
apt-get install -y gcc \
        libc6-dev \
        libencode-perl \
        wget \
        libzstd-dev \
        default-jdk \
        make
```

and run the command

```
perl Configure.pl --prefix=/usr --gen-moar --backends=moar,jvm --relocatable
```

for building. After the successful build, you will get `rakudo-m`, `rakudo-gdb-m`, `rakudo-valgrind-m`, `rakudo-lldb-m` for `moar` backend and 
`rakudo-j`, `rakudo-debug-j` for `jvm` backends.

#### Javascript and Moar backends

---

You cannot build isolated javascript backend. When building the `js` backend [you must also build `moar`](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/tree/native-bigints#javascript-backend). So to build javascript backend, the command to build will be,

```
perl Configure.pl --prefix=/usr --gen-moar --backends=moar,js --relocatable
```

The extra dependencies to build `javascript` backend is availability of `nodejs`, `g++` and `npm` which can be obtained by

```
apt-get install gcc g++ \
        libc6-dev \
        libencode-perl \
        wget \
        libzstd-dev \
        nodejs \
        npm \
        make
```

But while building `javascript` backend, I got the following error,

```
'/usr/bin/perl' tools/build/npm-install-or-link.pl . src/vm/js/nqp-runtime nqp-runtime 
Can't exec "npm": No such file or directory at tools/build/npm-install-or-link.pl line 18.
=== SORRY! === `npm install /rakudo/nqp/src/vm/js/nqp-runtime` failed with exit code -1 (72057594037927935)
make: *** [Makefile:852: js-deps] Error 255
```

[Search](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/tree/master#javascript-backend) reveals that

> If you are developing nqp-js, you may want to pass the --link option to configure to have the nqp-runtime linked instead of installed

Though there is no problem building isolated `NQP`. I am unsure how to npm link while automating the build of rakudo.

#### ALL backends

---

I learnt that `ALL` indeed means `moar`, `jvm` and `js` backends. This is confirmed when you run the command

```
perl Configure.pl --prefix=/usr --gen-moar --backends=ALL --relocatable
```

you see the following running in your terminal:

```
/usr/bin/perl Configure.pl --prefix=/usr --make-install --git-protocol=https --relocatable --no-ignore-errors --silent-build --no-force-rebuild --backends=moar,jvm,js --gen-moar
```

The dependencies for this will be

```
apt-get install gcc g++ \
        libc6-dev \
        libencode-perl \
        wget \
        libzstd-dev \
        default-jdk \
        nodejs \
        npm \
        make
```

If Javascript backend can be successfully built by resolving `npm link` issue above, I am sure all backends: `moar`, `jvm` and `javascript` can be built.

So the issue left here is **how to npm link while building rakudo**. Hope somebody's expert help will resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for writing up your progress with good detail. "So the issue left here is how to npm link while building rakudo !" Although I know pretty much nothing about this stuff it sounds to me like it would be good if you wrote *another* SO that focuses on that specific issue (perhaps with a link back to this answer or original question). If you have resolved the problem since you last edited this answer then you can write that up as an answer.

Comment: @raiph Though I sorted out the `moarvm` and `jvm` backends, I have still not succeded to build `rakudo` with `javascript` backend. So the problem is only partially solved.

Comment: Then it sounds to me like it would be great if you posted another SO focusing on the bit that's not solved. Even if it gets no answers for a while I think it's better than the question being somewhat buried away at the end of your answer. TIA if you have the time to post it as a separate question.

Comment: @raiph Sure will post another SO on building `javascript` backend.